# Numero elevado a una potencia en c#

Tags: c#, funciones

Gente, buenas noches!
Adjunto el código al final.
Tengo que conseguir el resultado de un numero y de su exponente x^y sin usar la funcion **Math.pow()**.

Me quede atorado en el ciclo **for**, algo tengo que poner ahí, alguno me puede dar una mano? Se agradece de antemano.

```
        int x; //base
        int y; //exponente
        float resultado;
        Console.WriteLine("Ingresa un numero: ");
        x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("valor de la exponente? ");
        y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (y == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("resultado es 1");
        }
        if (y >= 1)
        {
            for ()
            {
                
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public int Potencia(int b, int e)
{
   int tmp = b;
   
   if(e == 0)
   {
      return 1;
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < e - 1; i++)
   {
      tmp = tmp * b;
   }

   return tmp;
}
```

Esta función recibe dos parámetros, la **base** y el **exponente**, se guarda en una **variable temporal** el valor de la **base** y se pregunta si el valor del **exponente** es **0**, de serlo se devuelve **1** ya que cualquier número elevado a la **0** da **1**, en caso contrario se hace un **ciclo for** que se ejecutará hasta que su contador **i**, sea igual al valor del **exponente - 1**, dentro de este ciclo se irá haciendo la multiplicación, automultiplicando el valor actual de la **variable** **temporal** por la **base**, retornando al final la **variable temporal**.

### **Actualización**:

Para calcular las potencias con el exponente positivo o negativo harías:

```
public decimal Potencia(int b, int e)
{
   decimal tmp = b;

   if(e == 0)
   {
       return 1;
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < Math.Abs(e) - 1; i++)
   {
      tmp = tmp * b;
   }

   if(e < 0)
   {
      tmp = 1 / tmp;
   }

   return tmp;
}
```

Aquí se cambia el tipo de datos que devuelve la función de **int** a **decimal**, ya que las operaciones con exponente negativo devuelven números con coma, igualmente se cambia el tipo de datos de la **variable tmp** a **decimal**. Se pregunta si el exponente es **0**, de serlo se retorna **1**, caso contrario se ejecuta un **ciclo for** donde se calcula el valor absoluto de la **variable e** para asegurarnos que siempre sea positivo, dentro del **ciclo for** se van haciendo las multiplicaciones y cuando se sale del ciclo se pregunta si el exponente es negativo, de serlo se halla el inverso del resultado final de las multiplicaciones realizadas, de ser positivo solo se devuelve el resultado final de las multiplicaciones realizadas.

También como reto podríamos usar **Linq**:

```
public decimal PotenciaLinq(int b, int e)
{
    if(e == 0)
    {
        return 1
    }

    decimal resultado = Enumerable.Repeat(b, Math.Abs(e)).Aggregate((x, y) => x * y);

    return (e > 0) ? resultado : 1 / resultado;
}
```

Se crea un **IEnumerable**, que va a repetir n-veces el valor de la base, atendiendo al valor del exponente, es decir si el exponente tiene valor **3** y la base valor **2** el **IEnumerable** tendrá **3** elementos con valor **2**. Posteriormente se usa el **método extensor Aggregate** que será el encargado de multiplicar todos los elementos del **IEnumerable**.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar esta opción sin usar `Math.pow()` definiendo un resultado de 1 cuando el exponente es 0, cuando el valor es mayor a 0 iteras usando el operador `*=` y cuando el valor es menor de 0 iteras usando el operador `/=` .

```
public double Pow(double num, int pow)
{
    double resultado = 1; //valor default cuando el exponente es 0.
    if (pow > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= pow; ++i)
        {
            resultado *= num;
        }
    }
    else if (pow < 0)
    {
        for (int i = -1; i >= pow; --i)
        {
            resultado /= num;
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Ejemplos:

`Pow(2,3)` salida:  `8`

`Pow(3,2)` salida:  `9`

`Pow(2,4)` salida:  `16`

`Pow(2,0)` salida:  `1`

`Pow(2,-1)` salida:  `0.5`

De acuerdo a el ejemplo anterior, este sería el código adecuado a tu pregunta:

```
    int x; //base
    int y; //exponente
    float resultado = 1;
    Console.WriteLine("Ingresa un numero: ");
    x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("valor de la exponente? ");
    y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (y == 0) 
    {
        //valor es 1 cuando el exponente es 0.
        //Console.WriteLine("resultado es 1");                
    }
    else if (y > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= y; ++i)
        {
            resultado *= x;
        }
    }
    else if (y < 0)
    {
        for (int i = -1; i >= y; --i)
        {
            resultado /= x;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("resultado es " + resultado);
```

Answer (score 0):

De manera recursiva:

```
public static decimal Potencia(int b, uint e) => e switch
{
    0 => 1,
    _ => b * Potencia(b, e - 1),
};
```

Ajustar la función anterior para exponentes negativos es simple, cuando sea el caso, cambiarnos el exponente a positivo ( multiplicamos por `-1`) y lo pasamos como denominador

```
public static decimal Potencia(decimal b, int e) => e switch
{
    0 => 1,
    < 0 => 1 / Potencia(b, e * -1),
    _ => b * Potencia(b, e - 1),
};
```

---

Evidentemente esto es un ejercicio algoritmico más que práctico, ya que por un lado no se implementa para exponentes decimales (raíces) y por que `C#` (.net para ser especifico) cuenta con la librería `Math` que tiene la función `Math.Pow`.

Como dato curioso, la librería `Math` está escrita mayoritariamente en `C++` y compilada según el sistema operativo para maximizar la eficiencia. Pero no es así en el caso de los `BigInteger` que su implementación de `Pow` está escrita en `C#`